# Windows 10 clipboard history stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I used to enjoy the clipboard history that Windows 10 provides until my work PC has been put on the office domain, after that, I get the following when I press <kbd>Win-key</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

---

[image]

---

The things I tried many times and that didn't work:

- asking my pc administrators if they could fix
- disabling and re-enabling it from settings
- disabling and re-enabling it from group policy
- disabling and re-enabling it from the registry
- installing a third-party clipboard history software...this worked but I want the windows' one, fast accessible

Windows 10 Pro v.1809 (OS build 17763.1039)

Is anybody else facing this issue? I crave for this feature... please.